# Listar as reservas por Administrador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando listar minhas reservas por administradores diferentes. Porém, da forma como fiz, ele lista todas as reservas.

Esse é o método que estou usando:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Administrador administrador = db.Administradores.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == User.Identity.Name);
        if (administrador != null)
        {
            return View(db.Reservas.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


    }
```

Classe Reserva:

```
public class Reserva
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservaID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o horário para reserva")]
    [DisplayName("Horário")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string Horario { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o limite de pedidos/hora")]
    [DisplayName("Limite de Pedidos/Hora")]
    public int LimitePedidos { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a mesa")]
    [DisplayName("Mesa")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "A mesa deve ter no máximo 10 caracteres")]
    public string Mesa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o valor da reserva")]
    [DisplayName("Valor")]
    public double Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Restaurante:

```
public abstract class Restaurante
{
    [Key]
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do Restaurante")]
    [DisplayName("Restaurante")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do restaurante deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o tipo de cozinha")]
    [DisplayName("Cozinha")]
    public int CozinhaID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cozinha Cozinha { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone")]
    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "O número de telefone deve haver 12 caracteres.")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CNPJ")]
    [DisplayName("Cnpj")]
    [StringLength(18, MinimumLength = 18, ErrorMessage = "O CNPJ deve haver no máximo, 18 caracteres.")]
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CEP")]
    [DisplayName("CEP")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "O CEP deve haver no máximo 9 caracteres.")]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a Cidade")]
    [DisplayName("Cidade")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A cidade deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Estado")]
    [DisplayName("Estado")]
    [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "A sigla do estado deve haver 2 caracteres.")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Bairro")]
    [DisplayName("Bairro")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O bairro deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a Rua")]
    [DisplayName("Rua")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A rua deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Rua { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a número do estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Número")]
    public int NumRua { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do responsável pelo estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do responsável deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string NomeResp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o sobrenome do responsável pelo estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Sobrenome")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O sobrenome do responsável deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string SobrenomeResp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Email")]
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O email deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Celular")]
    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "O número de celular deve haver entre 10 e 15 caracteres.")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha")]
    [DisplayName("Senha")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter entre 3 e 50 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual Reserva Reserva { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

}
```

Restaurante é `abstract`, pois a classe Administrador herda todos os campos dela. Mas ela está vazia.

Comment: dentro de Reservas existe alguma coisa que indique que é de um determinado Administrador?, coloque as classes Reservas e Administrador na sua pergunta

Comment: Tá ai. Coloquei.

Comment: Está gravando certo isso ai? tipo tem valores em Restaurante? #estranho

Comment: Tem ué, é só uma abstract. É classe mãe. Os cadastros, edições, eu faço todos com a classe Administrador, que herda os campos da classe Restaurante. Mas no banco de dados é salvo na tabela restaurante. =)

Comment: Então eu não faria assim, porque na classe Administrador não tem campos adicionais e não vejo lógica para tanto. Se tem que pegar a relação entre os campos que na sua classe Restaurante não tem!?

Comment: Mas é só um detalhe que pode ser alterado. A questão é, eu quero listar as reservas a partir do administrador. Só isso. Mas não sei como escrever isso dentro do método.

Comment: Qual é o campo (ou chave) que relaciona Reserva e Restaurante, pensando em modelo de Classe (lógico) relacionado com modelo de banco (fisico) ???

Comment: Como está escrito no código acima, o restaurante pega o atributo ReservaID de Reserva. E reserva tem restaurantes.

Comment: Cade o campo ReservarId dentro de Restaurante? só lembrando em Entity Framework ele tem que existir! (diferente por exemplo de Nhibernate)

Comment: Vou colocar. Logo após isso, qual o procedimento para listar? 
O método, no caso.

Comment: Primeira coisa, arrumar todo o seu layout, colocando as chaves e estruturando sua base para o `ORM Entity Framework`. Tem uma linha `Administrador administrador = db.Administradores.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == User.Identity.Name);` se trouxer o administrador logo tem reservas e restaurante tudo pelos relacionamentos. Sem os relacionamento funcionando fica complicado e com eles é a resposta do que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Isto aqui traz todas as reservas, pelo óbvio:

```
return View(db.Reservas.ToList());
```

Esta modelagem não faz o menor sentido. Uma reserva só pode pertencer a um restaurante:

```
public class Reserva
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservaID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
}
```

Troque para:

```
public class Reserva
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservaID { get; set; }
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }
}
```

Pela sua modelagem, não existe uma correlação entre `Restaurante` e `Administrador`. Isso precisa ser definido de alguma forma.

Minha sugestão é vincular `Administrador` a uma `Cozinha`. Por exemplo:

```
public class AdministradorCozinha
{
    [Key]
    public int AdministradorCozinhaID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_UQ_AdministradorCozinha_Administrador_Cozinha", Order = 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int AdministradorID { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_UQ_AdministradorCozinha_Administrador_Cozinha", Order = 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int CozinhaID { get; set; }

    public virtual Administrador Administrador { get; set; }
    public virtual Cozinha Cozinha { get; set; }
}
```

Aí fica simples:

```
public class Administrador 
{
    [Key]
    public int AdministradorID { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<AdministradorCozinha> Cozinhas { get; set; }
}
```

Por fim:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var administrador = db.Administradores
                          .Include(a => a.Cozinhas)
                          .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == User.Identity.Name);

    if (administrador != null)
    {
        return View(administrador.Cozinhas.SelectMany(c => c.Reservas));
    }

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```